# Esta edição foi supérflua ou prejudicou a legibilidade?

Tags: debate, edição

Fiz esta melhoria na questão:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/111226

Porém o AP a rejeitou, vocês acham que prejudicou a legibilidade ou foi supérflua?

Comment: Particularmente, eu não acho. Eu costumo editar esse tipo de coisa, só que no meu caso não passa por aprovação. A correção da pontuação é sempre bem vinda.

Comment: Não achei supérflua, pelo contrário foi ótima, o AP quem não entende muito bem o intuito da "edição comunitária", sua edição está de parabéns, continue com o bom trabalho.

Comment: Aproveitei e editei porque tinha muita coisa que realmente não era necessária na pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/205637/3

Comment: Postei isso pra ele: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205637/retornar-dados-de-uma-classe-para-index#comment421369_205637

Comment: Deixei um comentário também após ele responder o @bigown: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205637/retornar-dados-de-uma-classe-para-index#comment421497_205637

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento muito obrigado, prezo pelo bom uso da Língua Portuguesa e vou continuar fazendo este trabalho :)

Answer (score 9):

Você topou com um tipo de usuário que fica ofendido quando alguém mexe no post dele. Demoram, mas terminam entendendo que faz parte do modelo do site: [**Por que as pessoas podem editar minhas publicações? Como funciona a edição?** - Central de ajuda - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/editing).

Pode continuar editando o que encontrar pela frente que precise de melhorias. É um direito de todo usuário do site.

Até dava para jogar o Livro da Lei `*` na cabeça deles mas não é necessário chegar a tal extremo.

`*` *"Seu post já não é seu, agora está licenciado como [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), vide rodapé do site."*

> [image: licensed]